# Suppose that $E \subset \mathbb{R}$. If $E \cap F$ is Lebesgue measurable for all measurable $F$ such that $m(F)$ is finite, then $E$ is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose that $E \subset \mathbb{R}$. If $E \cap F$ is Lebesgue measurable for all measurable $F$ such that $m(F)$ is finite, then $E$ is measurable.

I have spent hours trying to prove this statement. Any hints? Note: $m(F)$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Hint: try $F_n = [n, n+1)$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thanks, I think I see what to do. Each $F_n$ has finite measure, so $A \cap F_n$ is measurable by assumption. Also, $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}{F_n} = \mathbb{R}$. So we can write $A = A \cap \mathbb{R} = A \cap\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}{F_n} = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}{A \cap F_n}$, which is a countable union of measurable sets.